# Write data in the specific point with Python

Tags: python

I have a .gz file, and open with following code:

```
fin = GzipFile(fileName, "wb")
```

The data in this file are something like this:

```
# jobname
# string-name0 string-name1 string-name3 string-name4 string-name5 
# time
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
```

The first three lines are string, then the data. Now I want to replace the data at the third column, the new data is saved in an array. The final data will be as followings.

```
# jobname
# string-name0 string-name1 string-name3 string-name4 string-name5 
# time
1  2  31  4  5
6  7  81  9  10
11 12 131 14 15
```

So how can I do that in Python? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way I think it can be achieved is to read the original file and write the unchanged data along with the changed one to a new temporary file. Use this temporary file to replace the original one.

As of replacing the data is concerned, you can simply read through the file one by one and replace third element with the data in array. Something like

```
i = 0
for lines in file:
    # Skips the comments
    data = lines.split()
    data[2] = new_data[i]
    i = i + 1
    # Write to some temp file here
# Replace original file with temp file
```

To create a temporary file, you can use `tempfile` module of python.

`>>> import tempfile`

Answer (score 0):

Open file, read it lines, split by space, make your changes, and join it again

```
import gzip
import shutil
filename = 'file.txt.gz'
new_filename = 'new.file.txt.gz'
with gzip.open(filename,'rb') as f, gzip.open(new_filename,'wb') as f_out :
    lines = [l.split(" ") for l in f.readlines() if l and l.strip()] #remove trailings and empty lines
    for idx,l in enumerate(lines):
        if l[0]!="#":
            l[2] = l[2]+"1"          #your replacement
        lines[idx] = ' '.join(l)     #rebuild line as string

    f_out.write(''.join(lines))
shutil.move(new_filename,filename)   #finally, move the temp file to file
```

Comment: Thank you very much. is idx the index number of lines?

Comment: enumerate is the pythonic way to get the index of iteration loop, so yes idx is the index number of lines

Comment: lines[idx] = ''.join(l) TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, numpy.float64 found

Comment: since lines is data read from file, it should be a string. Could you print l values?

Comment: ['', '', '4.000000281197e-05\n']

Comment: ['"pos.x"', '"pos.y"', '"pos.z"', '"volume"', '"rho"', '"vel.x"', '"vel.y"', '"vel.z"', '', '"p"', '"a"', '"mu"', '"k[0]"', '"mu_t"', '"k_t"', '"S"', '"tke"', '"omega"', '"massf[0]-CO2"', '"e[0]"', '"T[0]"\n']

Comment: ['2.544031456650e-02', '1.040671238778e-04', '-5.529976786007e-06', '2.772328058507e-14', '2.382715544720e+01', '1.100933268338e+01', '2.274601314501e+01', '1.821812734356e-02', '1.366962461781e+06', '2.718000567350e+02', '1.519262389777e-05', '1.689694089256e-02', '0.000000000000e+00', '0.000000000000e+00', '0', '0.000000000000e+00', '1.000000000000e+00', '1.000000000000e+00', '1.994088957370e+05', '3.036645988493e+02\n']

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foil-deformation.py", line 304, in <module>
    main(uoDict)
  File "foil-deformation.py", line 279, in main
    process_deformation(ib, nib, flow1, grid1, flow2, grid2, flow2, grid2, jobName)
  File "foil-deformation.py", line 242, in process_deformation
    write_flow_grid(ib, new_f, new_g, jobName)
  File "foil-deformation.py", line 226, in write_flow_grid
    lines[idx] = ''.join(l)
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, numpy.float64 found

Comment: change the name of var l, to another a litle bit more complex. Maybe l  name was used in your script

Comment: lines[idx] = ''.join(ldata)
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, numpy.float64 found

Comment: a last thing, try to comment the replacement statements.